# Navbar toggle does not collapse after expanding

Tags: python, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

Hi i have a navbar that will not be collapsed once it has been expanded.

If anyone could take a look at my code and give me some advice that would be of great help to me.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Show Rooms</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          {% if session['username'] %}
          <a id='change_username_btn' class="nav-link" href="#">{{ session['username'] }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href= "{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log Out</a>
        </li>

          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id='change_username_btn' class="nav-link" href="#">Click Here to Enter Username<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>

          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

EDIT

Like what people have helped to mention before. The issue i was experiencing was because i am trying to use a responsive navbar which was causing the issue.

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: there is one error
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico 404 (NOT FOUND)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a simple problem.
you are trying to collapse a **responsive navbar** so it won't collapse well.
you had to remove `navbar-collapse` class to prevent going responsive.

try this (i didn't change your design) :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Show Rooms</button>

     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a id='change_username_btn' class="nav-link" href="#">Name <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href= "{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log Out</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```